# Big Query : how to parse timestamp string into timestamp when timestamp string contains millisecs fraction separated by colon

Tags: google-bigquery

How to parse to timestamp from a timestamp string with value of milliseconds separated by colon instead of dot?
Eg: "2017-08-18 16:04:40:890" I have tried with ('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E3S') but its giving me failed to parse string error.

`select parse_timestamp('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E3S','2017-08-18 16:04:40:890')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the : with an dot.

Such functions take lots of processing power and slow down queries, you should save the data always in as a date datatype

```
select parse_timestamp('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E3S'
, REGEXP_REPLACE('2017-08-18 16:04:40:890', r'(.*):([0-9]{3})$', r'\1.\2' ));
```

[image]

Comment: unfortunately data is already in string format (we are migrating from Postgres SQL to BQ). We are already using regex related extract operations and do you think its more costly like we should avoid it whenever possible. More over why BQ  is not support reading of timestamp string  milliseconds separated by colon while most other databases supports this. Also ``` select date_diff( cast('2024-01-01' as date), cast('2022-12-31' as date), YEAR)``` returns 2, as difference between these two dates, which seems like they are just substracting Year from Year, not doing actual date diff?

Comment: the dot is standard, so the is no need to have different separators, but when you only use Bigquery make an uodate and then convert the column, so you only need to to run it once